# Gradle builds forever in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I just installed AndroidStudio in my System

I am trying to create my Very First Project .

I set up JAVA_HOME and Android SDK path that has been used previuosly by eclipse in Android Studio

Android SDK has the below versions for Tools and Platform
Android SDK Tools - 22.6.2
SDK Platform - 19

As soon as started Android studio downloaded the Gradle-1.12 in the below path

C:\Users\DELL.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-1.12-all

after that it shows the build screen as below. This screen is shown for ever .  It is not moving further. can anyone help me in this. I am sad!

[image]

Comment: Do you use any proxy server? When gradle is synching it may need some files to download

Comment: I am not using any proxy server.